# Jenkins Visual Studio Expire In 19 Days

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I tried to google and stackoverflow but no luck, I can't find any solution to my specific issue.

Long story short, I need visual studio to build the web projects via jenkins, I tried installing just SDK + MSBuild but it doesn't work, and stackoverflow actually suggested installing visual studio which solved the problem.

I have a registered account with visual studio but problem is, jenkins runs as SYSTEM user and visual studio is NOT logged in with that user.

Is it possible to pass, say, the subscription id to the command line tool, or somehow spoof as SYSTEM and log in to visual studio?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to pass, say, the subscription id to the command line tool, or somehow spoof as SYSTEM and log in to visual studio?

As far as I know, you could not pass the subscription id to the command line tool.  If you want to unlock your Visual Studio, you can enter a product key to unlock it.

When you paid active subscription associated with your account, you have  access downloads and product keys.

https://my.visualstudio.com/productkeys

Comment: Thanks Leo, but my paid subscription is with visual studio 2017... I can't seem to use that for 2015 edition.

Comment: @BruceLi, since you paid subscription is visual studio 2017, you could not get the product key for Visual Studio 2015. To resolve this issue, I suggest that you can update the Visual Studio 2015 to Visual Studio 2017 on the jenkins server.

Comment: Thanks Leo, but our old code base requires older version of visual studio :( seems there's no way out now...